# How can I create a table with same attributes of a View another system delivers me?

Tags: oracle, view, create-table

An external system granted to my system a view named `V_EXT` so that I can make selections on it, reading all its content:

```
SELECT *
FROM V_EXT;
```

this view has a lot of fields and I would like to create an empty table in my system with the exactly same attributes of this view (same names and same types). Is there a way to do this without simply guessing from the content I received what each attribute is?

I am using Oracle SQL Developer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With Code.

```
create table objects_copy2
 as
  select *
    from all_objects
    where 1=2; -- add this line if you want NO data, otherwise you get all the data too
```

With SQL Developer specifically, it's actually harder. You would need to find the underlying OBJECT(s) used in the query. Then look up those data types, and manually build out your CREATE TABLE statement.

CREATE TABLE AS SELECT is the way to go. ([Docs](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/sqlrf/CREATE-TABLE.html#GUID-F9CE0CC3-13AE-4744-A43C-EAC7A71AAAB6))

Note there are some limitations, for example this won't pick up Identity Column definitions from the source table used in the view.

An example:

[image]

Comment: Right, I can `DELETE` the content in a second time. I wasn't thinking. Thanks.

Comment: @Rexam refresh my answer - just add a WHERE CLAUSE to restrict what data you want included